# Over with where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'd like to get a result like this using over():

```
Id | Name | Salary | Average |
1  | User1| 1000   | 2000 |
```

I'm currently using this :

```
WITH users AS (
   SELECT us_id, us_name, us_salary, avg(us_salary) over()
   FROM t_user_us
)
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE us_name = 'User 1';
```

Is it possible to do it in a simpler way ?

Statements :

```
CREATE TABLE T_USER_US (
   US_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   US_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   US_salary INTEGER NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO T_USER_US ("us_name","us_salary")
VALUES ('User 1',1000), ('User 2',2000), ('User 3',3000);
```

Comment: what would be simpler?.. skipping first step to calculate average?.. Semantically shorter?..

Comment: Why do you use  CTE in this case? Why not directly query to table?

Comment: I heard about OVER() with partitoning, that's what I was talking about

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to neither use a window function nor a common table expressions:

```
SELECT us_id, 
       us_name, 
       us_salary, 
       (select avg(us_salary) from t_user_us) as avg_salary
FROM t_user_us
WHERE us_name = 'User 1';
```